# Adding role after receiving confirmation

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to add role once someone has joined and got the "y" confirmation from someone in the same channel

Not sure if I can add another async in the middle...

Sorry if it is a very obvious question but most answers I got online were quite outdated and the docs didn't answer all my questions

This is my attempt

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
 await channel.send("{} has just joined. \nDo you know them (y/n)?".format(member.name))
 print("someone joined")
  async def on_message(message):
   if "y" in message.content:
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name="Hey i know you")
    await member.add_roles(role, atomic=True)
    await message.channel.send("added Hey i know you to {}".format(member.name))
```

Comment: And what is the problem now?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I got some help on the python discord telling to use wait_for to check for the response.  I hope you do not mind letting me know how to insert it where ```async def on_message(message):
   if "y" in message.content:``` is

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by using the [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) function.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(your channel id)
    guild = client.get_guild(your guild id)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} joined!")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await channel.send("{} has just joined. \nDo you know them (y/n)?".format(member.name))
    msg = await client.wait_for("message")
    if msg.content == "y":
        role = guild.get_role(your rold id)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await channel.send("Added role!")
    elif msg.content == "n":
        await channel.send("i wont add the role!")
        return
```

Comment: Note: If the `timeout` keyword-only argument is passed with a value that isn't `None` to `client.wait_for()`, the `client.wait_for()` call should be inside of a `try` clause, so that, if raised, the `asyncio.TimeoutError` exception can be handled.